# Materials on important "concepts" in programming

Tags: oop, testing, functional-programming, language-concepts

I'm looking for materials (book, video lecture, ...) that explain "important concepts" in programming such as interface and implementation, types and values, subtyping and inheritance, polymorphism, referential transparency and side effect, immutability, regression/unit/integrated testing etc.
I need the material to teach some of my junior colleagues. They just know the syntax of C and have only little programming experiences with toy problems. 
But they are experts on our own subject (some kind of mathematical data processing).
I think those concepts could give a quick guide for my colleagues to think how to express and organize their ideas with a programming language.
I know that there is no single "theme" connecting those concepts. So I hardly expect that there exists a material dealing with much of the concepts. But, on the other hand, I think people want such all-in-one materials. So I think there could be a little chance that such materials exist. Any recommendation?

Comment: you could use this: http://www.onlineprogrammingbooks.com/visualbasic-net/

Comment: [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) covers quite a lot of the topics you are interested in.

Comment: See introduction to programming and informatics/cs on coursera.org and edx.org, for the rest this question is far too broad.